# Finding the distribution of a limit of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm having some troubles with the following problem:

Given a sequence of i.i.d. exponential random variables $(X_n)$ with parameter one, what is the distribution of $Y := \limsup_n X_n/\log n$?

If I try to calculate the cumulative distribution of $Y$ I just get zero:
$$
    0 \le \mathbb{P}(Y \le t) = \int_0^t \limsup_n \frac{e^{-x}}{\log n} dx = \limsup_n
    \frac{1}{\log n} \int_0^t e^{-x} dx \le \limsup_n \frac{1}{\log n} = 0
$$
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you get the density function of $Y$?

Comment: From the definition of $Y$, swapping $X_n$ with its density function.

Comment: That makes no sense. You cannot do such things. In fact you don't even know that the density of $Y$  exists.